# How to reverse or construct a belief in jason (agentspeak)?

Tags: prolog, agent, multi-agent

I would like to do the following:

I have a initial goal with an argument as a belief, and I would like to reverse it, so that the belief's argument becomes the new belief, and the argument becomes the beliefname.

Something like this:

```
//Agent asker in project Test.mas2j
!translate(barks(dog)). //I would like to have the belief: dog(barks)
+!translate(T)<-
    T =.. [A,[B],C];
    .print("functor: ",A);
    .print("argument: ",B);
    //.print("source: ",C);
    +B(A);//<- I want something like this, but it gives a syntax error.
    +B. //<-this works, but it doesn't give the argument to it
```

So, my question is, hogy to constract beliefs in this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Construct the term like you do for `T`:

```
...
X =.. [B,[A]]; // constructs the belief
+X; // adds the belief to the current belief base
...
```

From the book [Programming Multi-Agent Systems in AgentSpeak using Jason](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470029005.html):

> One operator also available in Prolog that
>   works slightly differently here (because of the predicate annotations not available
>   in Prolog) is ‘`=..`’, which is used to deconstruct a literal into a list. The resulting
>   list has the format `[functor, list of arguments, list of annotations]`, for example:
>   `p(b,c)[a1,a2] =.. [p, [b,c], [a1,a2]]`.

Comment: In the meantime, I've figured it out. Your solution is syntacticly incorrect, but it's pretty close. If you dont mind, I will edit it, then accept it.

Comment: Good! I tried the following code which worked very well!
!translate(barks(dog)). +!translate(T) <- T =.. [A,[B],C]; X =.. [B,[A]]; +X.